# Should I use ExecutorService?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, executorservice

In my application, I am executing a bunch of SQL queries like a job and the details of the execution, which are inserted into a table. As soon as any record is inserted,the listener should pick it up and start monitoring the execution status and update the status in the same table.

My front-end is ready and till now I am able to execute the job(multiple queries) and insert the details in table.  Now I want to capture the status of execution and also I should be able to end ,pause ,restart the execution.

While I am going through multithreading part, I came across ExecutorService.

***My question is should I do this using ExecutorService? or is there any other way?***

Please share any tutorial links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case i think you can use ExecutorService and create jobs in [Callable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) objects that will help you to get the status of your running job it the form of [Future objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html).

For tutorial i would prefer [this](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html) , it has basic information about concurrent package.

Answer (score 0):

I have used ExecutorService to run parallel unit tests. And found it very successful. So I would suggest that you use it. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141648/concurrent-junit-tests-with-parameters/10239869#10239869)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the answers to my question here could help a bit with capturing the status of a task.

[how-to-get-to-futuretask-execution-state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933219/how-to-get-to-futuretask-execution-state)

While Executors framework is pretty powerful and could be used in almost any case, 
perhaps you should have a look at concurrency libraries like [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) , which would have a lot of the problems you are gonna encounter if using Executors already solved.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can `ExecuteService`, `Callable` and `Future` to achieve this.

Sample code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class CallableDemo{
    public CallableDemo(){
        System.out.println("creating service");
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

        System.out.println("Start");
        List<MyCallable> futureList = new ArrayList<MyCallable>();
        for ( int i=0; i<10; i++){
            MyCallable myCallable = new MyCallable();
            Future future = service.submit(myCallable);
            try{
                System.out.println("future.isDone = " + future.isDone());
                /* You can use future.get() blocking call set time out*/
                System.out.println("future: call ="+future.get());
            }
            catch (CancellationException ce) {
                ce.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException ee) {
                ee.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); // ignore/reset
            }
        }       
        service.shutdown();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        CallableDemo demo = new CallableDemo();
    }
    class MyCallable implements Callable<Long>{
        Long result = 0L;

        public MyCallable(){

        }
        public Long call(){
            // Add your business logic
            // set the result
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Key notes:

1. future.get() returns after computation of Callable task. Either you can block till completion of Callable or set time out for it.
2. If you get `InterruptedException`, interrupt the current thread and proceed.
3. Don't forget to call `shutdown()`