# TestNG using different parameters

Tags: testng

I have 100 test methods spread across 14 Java classes.(the numbers are only for example)
Now, I want to group 3 methods from the 1st class, 4 from the second class and so on into one @group.

Now, these test methods take in parameters and in their body, they also use the global variables in their respective classes

Now, in my xml file, I want to specify one  tag that will run all methods in the group several times, each time with different global and function parameters.

Note that I will not be able to use @Dataprovider because with it, I only specify the parameters needed by my methods.......i will not be able to change the global parameters in a data provider.....

Any help shall be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can inject data into a Super- Constructor like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6903037/1300626)

---------EDIT 1------------

You can retrieve data via [ITestContext](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/ITestContext.html)

like

```
@Test
public void test(ITestContext context){
    String para = context.getCurrentXmlTest().getParameter("para");
}
```

but that's only to use with Strings.

Maybe you can use the described DataProvider/Factory setup in combination with this ITestContext and inject a wrapper- class

I will edit my answer if you have further questions

Comment: i want to keep my test data separate from my test methods.....bcoz that's a good design and xml's are a lot easier to read(im really handling very large number of testcases.....so is there no other way in TestNG?